# How to add text inside an SWT window: Java, Eclipse

Tags: java, widget, swt

I am extremely new to programming, as a matter of fact I began yesterday and have done both of the coding exercises included in Eclipse (Hello World and Hello World SWT) and would like to know how to add text inside this handy-dandy SWT window and possibly how to make choices? Or even a spot to input text? Pardon me if I'm a tad ambitious but after seeing how easy it was to make a text window, I thought it would be fairly easy to make a text adventure game. I would love any and all help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).

There are code examples for all the widgets.

---

To answer your question:

- Use `Label` or `Text` for simple text you want to display
- Use `Text` for input
- Use a group of `Button`s with style `SWT.RADIO` for radio selection buttons
- Use a `Button` with style `SWT.CHECK` for a checkbox

Also, [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/) is the overview of all the widgets there are.

---

And finally there is [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html) excellent tutorial by Vogella about SWT in general and of course every SWT developers bread and butter: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Good luck with your game :)

Comment: Oh, yes, thank you! Now I'm experiencing even more technical difficulty, as in, my SWT is in the wrong format, I need a 64x version of SWT 4.4, but the download is for 32x... Any help on that?

Comment: @TheMatrixThatIsJava Well, simply download the correct one from the homepage. Have a look at the Vogella tutorial. I think he covers that.

Comment: @TheMatrixThatIsJava http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.4-201406061215/#SWT